# Rails Counter Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a db schema with multiple counter caches.  Rather than have the counter caches spread across many tables, I'd like to have a table called user_counters with all of the various counter caches.  I'd update these caches from a service object with a method like this:

```
def update_user_counter(column, user_id)
  UserCounter.increment_counter(column, user_id)
end
```

But, the UserCounter record for the associated user will most likely not have the same ID as the user.  What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
def update_user_counter(column, user_id)    
  UserCounter.increment_counter(column, UserCounter.where('user_id = "#{user_id}"')
end
```

Any thoughts as to how I can accomplish this?  Thanks!!

Comment: Out of curiosity: why? There's some serious technical debt here in writing all that new code, so what advantage does this schema offer?

Comment: Good question...this user_counters table has roughly 10 counter cache columns that are used on many page views.  So, rather than run 10 individual queries to get each of the 10 cached counter values, I am able to run 1 query.  I don't have any other caching strategies running (e.g., memcached) so this seems like the most efficient alternate approach.

Comment: Have you considered implementing this using triggers inside the database? Yeah yeah, Rails doesn't think there should be any logic in the database but sometimes Rails is stupid and short sighted.

Comment: I don't have anything against triggers but I'd prefer to not abstract the counter manipulation to the db level just yet.  Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are 10 attributes associated with a User, is there any reason to not simply make them a part of the User model? If that is the case, the below code will still work (just make the method part of User instead of UserCounter).

If you want to implement it your way, I'd say first make sure that your `user_counters` table has an index on user_id (since Rails is dumb about adding indexes and FK's).

Then, you could do this (passing in "column" as a symbol):

```
class UserCounter < ActiveRecord::Base
  #other code

  def self.update_user_counter(column, user_id)
    counter = UserCounter.find_by_user_id(user_id)
    counter.update_attribute(column, counter.read_attribute(column) + 1)
    counter.save!
  end
end
```

And in your other model:

```
class SomeOtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Model code

  def update_counter(user)
    UserCounter.update_user_counter(:this_column, user.id)
  end
end
```

This solution (or using the update_counter method) both require two database hits, one for the lookup and one for the update. If you need the speed, you could write this directly in SQL:

```
query = "UPDATE user_counters SET #{column} = #{column} + 1 WHERE user_id = #{user_id};"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query);
```

This assumes that `user_id` is unique on `user_counters`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - They're currently in the User model but that model is getting really, really fat and loading the counters up as a part of the model is getting really heavy.  I knew I could do the find before the increment _counter method but I was more looking for a way to dynamically get the counter row ID at runtime (based on the user_id) - to take advantage of the fact that increment_counter executes a raw SQL command.

Comment: `UserCounter.where(user_id: user_id).id` would return the UserCounter row id, if that is what you need for the raw SQL. Either way, you are still making two round-trips to the DB (one for lookup, one for increment). Updating above answer to include what I think might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!  I marked the answer as correct because, technically, it is correct.  Unfortunately, though, this is sub-optimal because, as mentioned, there are still two round trips to the db.  Maybe I'll create my own increment_counter method to accomplish the task.  Meantime, on to frying bigger fish.

Comment: Yeah increment_counter is going to require you to know the user_counter_id upfront. If you don't want to use raw SQL, you could also consider caching this as part of the User model, if it is not a foreign key constraint already. I'm assuming you have the User loaded to get the user_id.